# How to extract text and save as excel file using python or JavaScript

Tags: python, json, pandas

How do I extract text from this PDF files where some data is in the form of table  while some are key value based data

eg:
https://drive.internxt.com/s/file/78f2d73478b832b2ab55/3edb275967deeca6ad33e7d53f2337c50d5dfb50e0aa525bb7f10d49dff1e2b4

This is what I have tried :

```
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl

from openpyxl import Workbook

pdfFileObj = open('sample.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader.numPages

pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
mytext = pageObj.extractText()


wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'MyPDF'
sheet['A1'] = mytext

wb.save('sample.xlsx')
print('Save')
```

However I'd like the data to be stored in the following format.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text from PDF files and save as CSV using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72612708/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-files-and-save-as-csv-using-python)

Comment: yes, need to get new solution for different PDF format

Comment: Can one pdf have more than 1 data entity here? or every page is expected to have only 1?

Comment: Also if one page can have 2 data entity please share a pdf like that

Comment: Thanks, what do you refer as 1 data entity in PDF file ?

Comment: There will be many sections starting from **Our Ref** and ending with **Notes** in PDF file. **All Notes to Client Name** will be only 1 portion as on Top page. There will be 1 image at the left hand side under Account History Report.

Comment: What I mean is the AccountHistoryReport that you have is it guranteed to be only one in every single pdf page or one pdf page can have multiple AccountHistoryReport

Comment: Account History Report is only one. Thee is image under AHR. Left hand side

Comment: yeah image is no problem, but just to be sure can you share the pdf with image attached?

Comment: Sorry, can’t share this one

Comment: Hi @Himanshu Poddar, pls kindly explain in code as well.

Comment: @kkk I am asking because the structure of page would become different, and when there is an image in the pdf, the code might not work

Comment: could I try your current code first ?

Comment: The link does not have the shared files anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245680/discussion-between-kkk-and-himanshu-poddar).

Comment: pls refresh browser,  could you come to chat ?

Comment: @kkk I have written an answer, please check and let me know if you have any doubt. All you need to change in the code is `pdf_path`.

Comment: Thanks for awesome code.please allow me some time to digest the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pdf does not have well defined tables, hence cannot use any tool to extract the entire data in one table format. What we can do is read the entire pdf as text. And process each data fields line by line by using regex to extract the data.

Before you move ahead, please install the pdfplumber package for python

```
pip install pdfplumber
```

### Assumptions

Here are some assumptions that I made for your pdf and accordingly I have written the code.

[image]

1. First line will always contain the title `Account History Report`.
2. Second line will contain the names `IMAGE         All Notes`
3. Third line will contain only the data `Date Created` in the form of key:value.
4. Fourth line will contain only the data `Number of Pages` in the form of key:value.
5. Fifth line will only contain the data `Client Code, Client Name`
6. Starting line 6, a pdf can have multiple data entity, these data entity for eg in this pdf is 2 but can be any  number of entity.
7. Each data entity will contain the following fields:
8. First line in data entity will contain only the data `Our Ref, Name, Ref 1, Ref 2`
9. Second line line will only contain data in the form as present in pdf `Amount, Total Paid, Balance, Date of A/C, Date Received`
10. Third line in data entity will contain the data `Last Paid, Amt Last Paid, Status, Collector`.
11. Fourth line will contain the column name `Date Notes`
12. The subsequent lines will contain data in the form of table until the next data entity is started.
13. I also assume that each data entity will contain the first data with key `Our Ref :`.
14. I assume that the data entity will be separated on the first line of each entity in the pattern of key values as `Our Ref :Value    Name: Value    Ref 1 :Value    Ref 2:value`

```
pattern = r'Our Ref.*?Name.*?Ref 1.*?Ref 2.*?'
```

15. Please note that the rectangle that I have created(thick black) in above image, I am calling those as data entity.
16. The final data will be stored in a dictionary(json) where the data entity will have key as dataentity1, dataentity2, dataentity3 based on the number of entities you have in your pdf.
17. The header details are stored in the json as key:value and I assume that each key will be present in header only once.

### CODE

Here is the simple elegant code, that gives you information from the pdf in the  form of json. In the output the first few field contains information from the header part, subsequent data entities can be found as data_entity 1 and 2.

In the below code all you need to change is `pdf_path`.

```
import pdfplumber
import re

# regex pattern for keys in line1 of data entity
my_regex_dict_line1 = {
    'Our Ref' : r'Our Ref :(.*?)Name',
    'Name' : r'Name:(.*?)Ref 1',
    'Ref 1' : r'Ref 1 :(.*?)Ref 2',
    'Ref 2' : r'Ref 2:(.*?)$'
}

# regex pattern for keys in line2 of data entity
my_regex_dict_line2 = {
    'Amount' : r'Amount:(.*?)Total Paid',
    'Total Paid' : r'Total Paid:(.*?)Balance',
    'Balance' : r'Balance:(.*?)Date of A/C',
    'Date of A/C' : r'Date of A/C:(.*?)Date Received',
    'Date Received' : r'Date Received:(.*?)$'
}

# regex pattern for keys in line3 of data entity
my_regex_dict_line3 ={
    'Last Paid' : r'Last Paid:(.*?)Amt Last Paid',
    'Amt Last Paid' : r'Amt Last Paid:(.*?)A/C\s+Status',
    'A/C Status': r'A/C\s+Status:(.*?)Collector',
    'Collector' : r'Collector :(.*?)$'
}

def preprocess_data(data):
    return [el.strip() for el in data.splitlines() if el.strip()]
    
def get_header_data(text, json_data = {}):
    header_data_list = preprocess_data(text)
    # third line in text of header contains Date Created field
    json_data['Date Created'] = re.search(r'Date Created:(.*?)$', header_data_list[2]).group(1).strip()
    # fourth line in text contains Number of Pages, Client Code, Client Name
    json_data['Number of Pages'] = re.search(r'Number of Pages:(.*?)$', header_data_list[3]).group(1).strip()
    # fifth line in text contains Client Code and ClientName
    json_data['Client Code'] = re.search(r'Client Code - (.*?)Client Name', header_data_list[4]).group(1).strip()
    json_data['ClientName'] = re.search(r'Client Name - (.*?)$', header_data_list[4]).group(1).strip()
    
def iterate_through_regex_and_populate_dictionaries(data_dict, regex_dict, text):
    ''' For the given pattern of regex_dict, this function iterates through each regex pattern and adds the key value to regex_dict dictionary '''
    for key, regex in regex_dict.items():
            matched_value = re.search(regex, text)
            if matched_value is not None:
                data_dict[key] = matched_value.group(1).strip()

def populate_date_notes(data_dict, text):
    ''' This function populates date and Notes in the data chunk in the form of list to data_dict dictionary '''
    data_dict['Date'] = []
    data_dict['Notes'] = []
    iter = 4
    while(iter < len(text)):
        date_match = re.search(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})',text[iter])
        data_dict['Date'].append(date_match.group(1).strip())
        notes_match = re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s*(.*?)$',text[iter])
        data_dict['Notes'].append(notes_match.group(1).strip())
        iter += 1   

data_index = 1
json_data = {}
pdf_path = r'C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Temp\sample3.pdf' # ENTER YOUR PDF PATH HERE
pdf_text = ''
data_entity_sep_pattern = r'(?=Our Ref.*?Name.*?Ref 1.*?Ref 2)'

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        index = 0
        while(index < len(pdf.pages)):
            page = pdf.pages[index]
            pdf_text += '\n' + page.extract_text()
            index += 1
            
    split_on_data_entity = re.split(data_entity_sep_pattern, pdf_text.strip())
    # first data in the split_on_data_entity list will contain the header information
    get_header_data(split_on_data_entity[0], json_data)
    while(data_index < len(split_on_data_entity)):
        data_entity = {}
        data_processed = preprocess_data(split_on_data_entity[data_index])
        iterate_through_regex_and_populate_dictionaries(data_entity, my_regex_dict_line1, data_processed[0])
        iterate_through_regex_and_populate_dictionaries(data_entity, my_regex_dict_line2, data_processed[1])
        iterate_through_regex_and_populate_dictionaries(data_entity, my_regex_dict_line3, data_processed[2])
        if(len(data_processed) > 3 and data_processed[3] != None and 'Date' in data_processed[3] and 'Notes' in data_processed[3]):
            populate_date_notes(data_entity, data_processed)
            json_data['data_entity' + str(data_index)] = data_entity
        data_index += 1
            
    print(json_data)
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Result string :**

```
{'Date Created': '18/04/2022', 'Number of Pages': '4', 'Client Code': '110203', 'ClientName': 'AWS PTE. LTD.', 'data_entity1': {'Our Ref': '2118881115', 'Name': 'Sky Blue', 'Ref 1': '12-34-56789-2021/2', 'Ref 2': 'F2021004444', 'Amount': '$100.11', 'Total Paid': '$0.00', 'Balance': '$100.11', 'Date of A/C': '01/08/2021', 'Date Received': '10/12/2021', 'Last Paid': '', 'Amt Last Paid': '', 'A/C Status': 'CLOSED', 'Collector': 'Sunny Jane', 'Date': ['04/03/2022'], 'Notes': ['Letter Dated 04 Mar 2022.']}, 'data_entity2': {'Our Ref': '2112221119', 'Name': 'Green Field', 'Ref 1': '98-76-54321-2021/1', 'Ref 2': 'F2021001111', 'Amount': '$233.88', 'Total Paid': '$0.00', 'Balance': '$233.88', 'Date of A/C': '01/08/2021', 'Date Received': '10/12/2021', 'Last Paid': '', 'Amt Last Paid': '', 'A/C Status': 'CURRENT', 'Collector': 'Sam Jason', 'Date': ['11/03/2022', '11/03/2022', '08/03/2022', '08/03/2022', '21/02/2022', '18/02/2022', '18/02/2022'], 'Notes': ['Email for payment', 'Case Status', 'to send a Letter', '845***Ringing, No reply', 'Letter printed - LET: LETTER 2', 'Letter sent - LET: LETTER 2', '845***Line busy']}}
```

Now once you got the data in the json format, you can load it in a csv file, as a data frame or whatever format you need the data to be in.

#### Save as xlsx

To save the same in a xlsx file in the format as shown in the image in the question above. We can use xlsx writer to do the same.
Please install the package using pip

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

From the previous code, we have our entire data in the variable json_data, we will be iterating through all the data entities and write the data to appropriate cell specified by `row, col` in the code.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sample.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet 1")
row = 0
col = 0

# write columns
columns = ['Account History Report', 'All Notes'] + [ key for key in json_data.keys() if 'data_entity' not in key ] + list(json_data['data_entity1'].keys())
worksheet.write_row(row, col,  tuple(columns))
row += 1

column_index_map = {}
for index, col in enumerate(columns):
    column_index_map[col] =  index

# write the header
worksheet.write(row, column_index_map['Date Created'],  json_data['Date Created'])
worksheet.write(row, column_index_map['Number of Pages'],  json_data['Number of Pages'])
worksheet.write(row, column_index_map['Client Code'],  json_data['Client Code'])
worksheet.write(row, column_index_map['ClientName'],  json_data['ClientName'])
data_entity_index = 1


#iterate through each data entity and for each key insert the values in the sheet
while True:
    data_entity_key = 'data_entity' + str(data_entity_index)
    row_size = 1
    if(json_data.get(data_entity_key) != None):
        for key, value in json_data.get(data_entity_key).items():
            if(type(value) == list):
                worksheet.write_column(row, column_index_map[key],  tuple(value))
                row_size = len(value)
            else:
                worksheet.write(row, column_index_map[key], value)
    else:
        break
    data_entity_index += 1
    row += row_size
    
workbook.close()
```

**Result :**
The above code creates a file `sample.xlsx` in the working directory.

[image]

Comment: @kkk could you please ask the same in a different question and share the link with me.

Comment: @ Himanshu Poddar, I am at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245680/discussion-between-kkk-and-himanshu-poddar